# how can i programmatically reposition the ExpandableSplitter

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetbar

Anyone know how to programmatically move the DevComponents ExpandableSplitter?

I have tried Location change, but that doesnt do anything.
and expanded, but I want the opposite effect of the expanded action.

I have a panel that is expanded via the splitter, stored in the ExpandableControl of the splitter.
and I want to set the splitter to show the ExpandableControl fully over the available space.

Comment: Is the control currently `Dock`ed to its parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found something that works, but there is still a minimul gap at the bottom which i cannot get rid of.

```
expandableSplitter2.Expanded = true;
panelTohide.Visible = false;
expandableSplitter2.Visible = false;

//to hide as much of the answer panel as possible
expandableSplitter2.MinExtra = 0;
expandableSplitter2.MaximumSize = new Size(1, 1);
expandableSplitter2.Height = 0;

expandableSplitter2.SplitPosition = this.Height;
```

but there will still a small gap at the bottom.

in answer to Paul Ruane, 
the hidepanel is `dock.fill`
the toppanel is `dock.top`
the expandablesplitter is `dock.top`

Comment: Understand that this is a really old post, but rather than setting .Location, you should set .SplitPosition.